# How to store the different html pages values into same row of the database?

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I have done the database connection like following form and inserted the values as shown in the code

insert.php

```
<html>
    <body>
        <?php
            $conn=new mysqli('localhost','root','');
            if($conn->connect_error){
               die("connection failed" .$conn->connect_error);
            }
            echo "DB connected successfully";
            mysqli_select_db($conn,"namesql_db");
            echo "\n DB is selected as Test successfully";
            $sql="INSERT INTO namesql_table(fname,fgender) VALUES('$_POST[fname]','$_POST[fgender]')";

            if($conn->query($sql)==TRUE){
               echo "New record created successfully";
            } 
            else {
               echo "Error:" .$sql."<br>" .$conn->error;
            }               
            mysqli_close($conn);
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

name.html

```
<html>
    <body>
        <head>
            <title>DIABETES RISK SCORE SYSTEM</title>
        </head>
        <body bgcolor="lightgreen" text="black" style="font-size:18pt  font-family:Garamond">
            <center>
                <h2>DIABETES RISK SCORE SYSTEM</h2>
            </center>
            <form action="insert.php" method="post">
                <br/><br/><br/>Enter your name:<input type="text" name="fname"pattern="  [A-Za-z]+" required /><br> <br>
                <input type="submit"/>
            </form>
            <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
            <a href="taketest.php" class="btn">BACK</a>
            <a href="Gender.html" class="btn">NEXT</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Gender.html

```
<html>
    <body>
        <head>
            <title>DIABETES RISK SCORE SYSTEM</title>
        </head>
        <body bgcolor="lightgreen" text="black" style="font-size:18pt;font-family:Garamond">
            <center>
                <h2>DIABETES RISK SCORE SYSTEM</h2>
            </center>
            <form action="insert.php" method="post">
                <br/><br/><br/>Enter your Gender:<br/><br/><br/><input type="radio"    name="fgender"value="female" checked />Female<br>
                <input type=radio name="fgender" value=male>Male</td><br> <br>
                <input type="submit"/>
            </form>
            <img src="mf.png" align="right" width="300" height="300"><br/><br/><br/> 
            <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
            <a href="name.php" class="btn">BACK</a>
            <a href="Age.html" class="btn">NEXT</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Once the database is connected ,i have created the table and inserted the value such that it is stored in the form

```
fname  fgender
ramya   -
   -   female
```

But actually i want to store the name and gender in one row itself that is

```
fname  fgender
ramya   female
```

Comment: You can't do this with 2 different form, because always will get first name and blank gender, and then empty name with only gender, with the $_POST

Comment: i.e. you can do that but is a lot tricky and need too much code, also using different page for 1 insert, you need to study jquery , to show second page and delete first without changing page, and post all the value at the same.

Comment: can u explain me with the little bit code.

Comment: get the return id from the first form, passi it as hidden in the second form and when you process the second form update the record with that id instead of doing an insert. Or just do a single form with the two fields that is much better also in terms of UX

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to solve:
1) Keep doing as it is and after a day, schedule a query to run that would fill the gender space with data below row and empty the same row of gender when its populated above

Example

```
fname fgender

salman   -

-      male


ramya    -


-      female
```

after a day

```
fname fgender


salman male


ramya female
```

OR

store one data(fname or fgender) in session or temporary variable and when you have both the field then execute the sql query

Hope that answers the question

Comment: are you serious?

Comment: yes brother, do you think i am wrong ? Please correct me